# 'this' argument has type const but function is not marked const c++ overload operator

Tags: c++

How do i fix this?

I'm getting error: `'this' argument has type const but function is not marked const c++ overload operator`

```
template <class T>
class Rational {
private:
    T n = 0;
    T d = 1;
public:
    Rational() = default;
    T numerator() {
        return n;
    }
    T denominator() {
        return d;
    }
};

template <class T>
inline bool const operator ==(const Rational <T> & lhs, const Rational <T>& rhs)  {

    return lhs.numerator() * rhs.denominator() == lhs.denominator() * rhs.numerator();

}
```

Comment: template <class T>
class Rational {
private:
  T n = 0;
  T d = 1;

public:
  Rational() = default;
  T numerator() {
    return n;
  }
  T denominator() {
    return d;
  }

Comment: You should put the information in the actual question by editing your question. I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that `numerator()` and `denominator()` member functions are not `const` member functions. Make them `const`. After that, the above function should work.

BTW, there is no need for the return type to be `bool const`. Keep it simple and change it to `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

If `numerator()` and `denominator()` are to be used to directly assign to `Rational`s internal member variables as well as being used in `const` contexts, you need two sets of overloads. One mutable and one `const`:

```
// mutable interface

T& Rational::numerator();
T& Rational::denominator();

// const interface if T may only be a fundamental integral type

T Rational::numerator() const;
T Rational::denominator() const;

// const interface if sizeof(T) may be > sizeof(T*)

T const& Rational::numerator() const;
T const& Rational::denominator() const;
```

Note, only one of the `const` interfaces may be used so you need to select one of them.

---

Here's an example of how it can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Rational {
public:
    // pass by value for fundamental types, by const& for other types
    using by_value_or_by_const_ref =
        std::conditional_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>, T, T const&>;

    Rational(by_value_or_by_const_ref n, by_value_or_by_const_ref d) :
        m_numerator(n), m_denominator(d) {}

    // mutable interface
    T& numerator() { return m_numerator; }
    T& denominator() { return m_denominator; }

    // const interface
    by_value_or_by_const_ref numerator() const { return m_numerator; }
    by_value_or_by_const_ref denominator() const { return m_denominator; }

private:
    T m_numerator;
    T m_denominator;
};

template<class T>
inline bool operator==(const Rational<T>& lhs, const Rational<T>& rhs) {
    // using const interface
    return lhs.numerator() * rhs.denominator() ==
           lhs.denominator() * rhs.numerator();
}

int main() {
    Rational<int> a(10, 20);
    Rational<int> b(10, 10);

    // using mutable interface
    a.denominator() /= 4;
    b.numerator() *= 2;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a == b) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, making num and denum  inside the class const fixed the problem